# Control symbol formed by escape character followed by return

Tags: tex-core, catcodes, parsing

Does the control symbol obtained by following the escape character by return (`\<return>`, catcode 0 then catcode 5) behave like the control space character (`\<space>`, catcode 0 then catcode 10)? It seems to:

```
\TeX\ blah
```

typesets the same way

```
 \TeX\
 blah
```

does. But I can't justify this behavior by tracing through the lexing process as described in the texbook. What exactly is tex doing here?

Comment: Recall that trailing spaces and tabs are removed from the line and that the `\endlinechar` is added, so what TeX sees is `<backslash><endlinechar>`.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

There's this in plain.tex

```
\def\^^M{\ } % control <return> = control <space>
\def\^^I{\ } % same for <tab>
```

Comment: To convince oneself that this is what is happening, one can add `\def\^^M{something else}` and see the results.

Comment: So it seems that the lexing map from nonletters (characters not of catcode 11) to control symbols isn't one-to-one. Are there any other instances of different strings `\<nonletter>` being lexed to the same control symbol other than `<nonletter> = <return>, <space>, <tab>`?

Comment: @fmg I don't understand your comment. There are other different nonletters `\!`, `\,`, etc. you mean if there's another case in which two non-letters end up expanding to the same thing? I don't think there's any other case, but you could do `\def\.{\,}` and `\.` would end up expanding to the same as `\,`. I'm not sure I understand what you are asking.

Comment: @manuel That's exactly what I was asking -- whether there are "naturally occuring" instances of `<escape><nonletter>` expanding to the same thing aside from `\<return>`, `\space`, and `\<tab>`. It seems not!

Comment: @fmg Precisely, this is not “naturally occuring”, Knuth defined `\<return>` and `\<tab>` to expand to `\<space>`. It's as if he defined `\def\a{\ } \def\b{\ } \def\c{\ }` all three macros `\a`, `\b`, `\c`, would expand to ``\ `` but by no means it's “natural”.

Comment: I wonder if there's a reason why this isn't `\let\^^M=\ % ...` plain.tex is usually so careful about conserving memory.